# Get the kernel version from lts package?

Tags: kernel, package-management, lts

How do I determine the kernel version that a package like `linux-image-generic-lts-saucy` will install? Basically I'd like to get what `uname -r` would report *before* I actually install this kernel so I can automate the configuration of grub.

Comment: Avinash Raj, that reports a number like: `3.11.0.17.16` is that equivalent to `3.11.0-17-generic`?

Comment: AvinashRaj you should submit as answer then

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because everything depends on the OS release not the kernel version. In your case Ubuntu `Saucy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the below command on terminal,

```
apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-lts-saucy
```

It will show the `linux-image-generic-lts-saucy`package along with it's version and some other details.

Comment: I think a cleaner way would be to simply look at the actual image package on which the dummy package depends i.e. `apt-cache depends linux-image-generic-lts-saucy`

Comment: Thanks, I used this to answer my similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525217/how-do-i-get-the-real-package-name-and-version-for-a-pseudo-package